# how to make Angular Component appear in HTML template?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, components

I'm developing a web application using **Angular 6**. I have a little problem: with this simple code inside in one of my services:

```
method() {
   document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<h1>Hello</h1>');
}
```

I can dynamically display html code every time I run. This happens, however, only because  is a native HTML tag. How can I do the same thing with an Angular component associated with an HTML template? For example, , it does not work this way ...

```
method() {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<myComponent>/myComponent>');
}
```

Can you help me with a solution that uses a few lines of code? I have to use this method in a service. Thanks.

Comment: you shouldnt mess with the dom like that in angular, you would be better using `*ngIf`'s on the components, or a for loop

Comment: https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-dynamic-components

Answer (score 0):

You should put your component into the DOM and use *ngIf, or some other guarding to decide when to show it:

```
<myComponent *ngIf="showComponent"></myComponent>
```

the variable `showComponent` would be set to true/false depending on the conditions you have regarding when to show your component.